# Edit a text file on Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have a text file with the following format:

```
Wind River Linux glibc_cgl (cgl) 3.0.3       


Build label: NDPGSN_5_0_SRC_GSN_LINUX_GPBOS_2
Build host: eselnvlx1114                     
Build date: Mon Mar 18 23:24:08 CET 2013     
Installed: Fri Jun 20 02:22:08 EEST 2014     
Last login: Fri Aug  8 11:37:08 2014 from 172
gsh list_imsins                              
=== sysadm@eqm01s14p2 ANCB ~ # gsh list_imsin
ps Class    Identifiers               |      
---------------------------------------      
A  imsins   -imsi  20201                     
A  imsins   -imsi  20205                     
A  imsins   -imsi  20210                     
A  imsins   -imsi  204045
```

I want to extract the numbers next to `-imsi`. The output would look like:

```
20201
20205
202210
204045
```

And after that process the output further, which I've already done. At first I was informed that the text format was static, so I wrote the following script:

```
for (( r=1; r<5; r++));
do
  awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' > N$r
  awk 'NR>12' IMSI$r.txt | awk '{print $NF "\r"}' >> out

done
```

I had 2 files as output because I needed to use both for other purposes.

Is there any way to make the script more flexible, to deal with dynamic text files?

As a possible solution, is it possible to make the script look for the phrase `-imsi` and grab the record after it? And continue doing so until it finds the end of file?

I tried doing that using `grep` and `awk` but I never got the right output. If you have any other ideas to do that please share.

Comment: Isn't `$x` always the same as `$r`? Why do you need two variables?

Comment: yea already fixed that I posted the script from an old file :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for something like:

```
$ awk '/-imsi/ {print $NF}' file
20201
20205
20210
204045
```

This prints the last word on those lines containing `-imsi`.

You can also use `grep` with a look-behind, to print the numbers after `-imsi`.

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=-imsi  )[0-9]*' file
20201
20205
20210
204045
```

Comment: Tested the first one worked great, added "\r" near the $NF so that the output would come on a new line.

Comment: I'm using cygwin maybe that's the issue

Comment: @Necro1992 Do you have any strange character in your file (maybe it comes from Windows environment)? If so, you can do `dos2unix` to the file before using this `awk`.